# draw bitmap radius with 1% to 100% in android

Tags: android, bitmap

Please help me to create round cornered bitmap creation with radius varying from 1% to 100%. I have tried my code is working in correctly in some density device and not coming with 100% round corners in some other device.

```
final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
       Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, output.getWidth() - margin3 - margin1,
output.getHeight() - margin3 - margin1), cornerDips, cornerDips, paint);

if (bitmap != output) {
    bitmap.recycle();
}
return output;
```

Comment: Yes I am using different bitmaps